# How to find consecutive intervals in mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have a table **visits** with fields: *personId*, *date*

```
+----------+------------+
| personId |    date    |
+----------+------------+
|        1 | 2020-05-04 |
|        1 | 2020-05-05 |
|        1 | 2020-05-06 |
|        1 | 2020-05-08 |
|        1 | 2020-05-09 |
|        2 | 2020-05-03 |
|        2 | 2020-05-04 |
|        2 | 2020-05-07 |
+----------+------------+
```

personId + date are unique, there can not be two records with the same date and personId

The question is: how to create mySQL query which will display consecutive visits intervals

```
+----------+------------+------------+-------+
| personId | dateStart  |  dateEnd   | count |
+----------+------------+------------+-------+
|        1 | 2020-05-04 | 2020-05-06 |     3 |
|        1 | 2020-05-08 | 2020-05-09 |     2 |
|        2 | 2020-05-03 | 2020-05-04 |     2 |
|        2 | 2020-05-07 | 2020-05-07 |     1 |
+----------+------------+------------+-------+
```

I found some similar issues but all of them have some particular differences, so I don't know exactly how to apply them for my case and would appreciate an example according to my table structure

Comment: Why is `2020-05-07` and `2020-05-07` consecutive? They're the same date and same row.

Comment: @Barmar, just because... one standalone day should be in list also

Comment: Do you have a primary key?

Comment: @Mihai, personId + date are unique

Comment: It might be an idea to be polite to those that are trying to help you

Comment: People above a certain reputation can see the deleted answers and comments thats why you have Strawberry`s comment.Didn't downvote btw.

Comment: Ok but dont be patronizing to people trying to help you for free.Social skills will take you a long way ,in life and online.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  pairs.person_id, 
  pairs.startDate, 
  pairs.endDate, 
  pairs.endDate - pairs.startDate + 1 as count 
FROM
(SELECT 
  t1.person_id, 
  t1.date as startDate, 
  MIN(t3.date) as endDate 
FROM visits as t1
   LEFT JOIN visits as t2 ON 
     t1.person_id = t2.person_id AND 
     t1.date - t2.date = 1
   LEFT JOIN visits as t3 ON 
     t1.person_id = t3.person_id AND 
     t1.date <= t3.date
     LEFT JOIN visits as t4 ON 
       t3.person_id = t4.person_id AND 
       t3.date - t4.date = -1
WHERE ISNULL(t2.date) AND ISNULL(t4.date)
GROUP BY t1.person_id, t1.date
) as pairs
```

explanation:

1) We find records (t1) that do not have previuous date (t2)

2) Lets join t1 records with records (t3) that do not have a next date

3) For each date from t1 lets find minimum from t3

That's it